# Swedish Unicode issues in python

Tags: python, unicode

I am new to this forum (this is my first question), so please bear with me. I am scraping a website in Swedish. It's using the ISO-8859-1 charset.

In the source it might look something like this:

```
<div class="fl icon-post-old"></div>
    2015-11-13, 15:09
    <a href="
```

Let's say I want to grab the date and time (this is not a real example).

```
threadcode=opener.open(threadurl).read()
threadcode2=threadcode.decode("ISO-8859-1")
post=re.findall(r'<div class="fl icon-post-old"></div>(.*?)<a',str(threadcode2))
post2=re.findall(r'<div class="fl icon-post-old"></div>(.*?)<a',str(threadcode))
print (post) #this is blank
print (post2) #this works fine
```

So, if I am searching for something in the "nice readable Swedish variable post", it does not seem to work. However, if I do the same search using the Unicode representation (which is not very useful) then the same search works.

Anyone of you nice programmers out there who knows what's going on here?

I can also add, if it helps that in some cases the search actually works... 
For example:

```
post=re.findall(r'Jag vill(.*?)bil',str(threadcode2))
```

This would work...

I am very confused.

Comment: Your strings must be unicode strings, here is a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327731/python-problems-with-regular-expression-and-unicode

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the [`re.UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag when passing unicode strings into [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
post=re.findall(r'<div class="fl icon-post-old"></div>(.*?)<a',threadcode2, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with Swedish. I think `re` is borking on the multiline. If you do something like:

```
post=re.findall(
  r'<div class="fl icon-post-old"></div>(.*?)<a',
  threadcode2.replace('\n','')
)
```

You'll get your expected result.